# Cant get my input value to appear on my functions

Tags: javascript, html

I want my use to enter a value and when they press Submit Calculations there should be a alert bar previewing an error message if value is null.

```
<form id= "form1"   class = "myform" action ="register.php" method "post">

<label> Loan Amount: </label>                   
<input  type = "text" class= "inputvalues" id = "loanAmm" placeholder = "Fill in the Details"> <br>

<input name = "submit_btn" type ="button"  onclick = "checkvalues();" id = "storevalue" value = "Submit Calculations"> <br>


</form> 

function checkvalues()
{
var loanAmount = document.forms["form1"]["loanAmm"].value;


if (loanAmount == null )
{

    alert("Re-enter value");

    return false; 

}

}
```

Comment: Did you have a question? You've told us the desired outcome, but there is no "clear problem statement".

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless.

Comment: when I enter a value and press submit. Nothing happens.

Comment: What value are you entering?

Comment: Have you looked at the Console? Are there any errors? Have you added `console.log` statements to see what the values you are testing actually are?

Comment: Im entering a numerical value. If the user submits a number than it should move on to the next step. If the input is blank then an alert message should appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing elements with document.forms["form1"], "form1" is the name of the form, not the id.  The same is true for document.forms["form1"]["loanAmm"] - "loanAmm" is the name of the input.

Best practice is to use the id to reference the input.

Also, use **addEventListener** to add the onclick handler because it separates the logic from the layout.

```js
document.getElementById("storevalue").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var loanAmount = document.getElementById("loanAmm").value;

  if (loanAmount.trim() === "") {

    alert("Loan amount cannot be blank");

    return false;

  } else {
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();
  }

});
```

```html
<form id="form1" class="myform" action="register.php" method "post">

  <label> Loan Amount: </label>
  <input type="text" class="inputvalues" id="loanAmm" placeholder="Fill in the Details"> <br>

  <input name="submit_btn" type="button" id="storevalue" value="Submit Calculations"> <br>


</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test should be :

```
if (loanAmount === '') {
    alert("Re-enter value");
    return false; 
}
```

If input is empty, the value is not null but empty.